# Extension of sheaf of Azumaya algebras and derived equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, brauer-groups

Suppose there is a smooth variety $X$ and a sheaf of algebra $\mathcal{B}$. Let $Z\subseteq X$ be a closed subvariety, whose codimension is large (say $\geq 2$). If the restriction of $\mathcal{B}$ to the open set $X-Z$ is a sheaf of Azumaya algebra. Is there any research related to the statement like :

There is another variety $X'$ and a sheaf of Azumaya algebra $\mathcal{A}$, such that $$D^b(X, \mathcal{B}) \cong D^b(X', \mathcal{A}).$$ By $D^b(X, \mathcal{B})$, I mean the bounded derived category of complexes of sheaf of $\mathcal{B}$-modules.

I wish $(X', \mathcal{A})$ to be reasonably closed to $(X, \mathcal{B})$, for example, $X, X'$ are birational..

Comment: "I wish $(X', \mathcal{A})$ to be reasonably closed to $(X', \mathcal{A})$". This shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Could you give me some hints?

Comment: What Niels is saying is that you have a typo in your last sentence.  You wrote $(X',\mathcal{A})$ twice.  Presumably one of those pairs should be $(X,\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: Hmm.  What are you going to do if $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{O}_Z$ for example?  Do you allow $X'$ to be disconnected?

Comment: I guess if $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \mathcal{O}_Z$, then I just let $X' = X, \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{O}_X$. I don't allow $X'$ to be disconnected.